# Custom Ultrasonic Sensor Schematic

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, level-shifting, ultrasound

I am trying to recreate this project. I have the circuit constructed on a breadboard. I am using an SP232 instead of a MAX232, a TIP42CG PNP instead of a BC557 PNP, and an Arduino Uno instead of an Arduino Nano. I am not getting any signal when I measure the T+ terminal on the transmitter with an oscilloscope. I have triple-checked all connections and the code so I am not sure what's wrong. Sorry, the schematic is not the most straightforward. I am new to electrical design and I was wondering if there were any obvious design issues with this schematic?

Link to project: http://electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut36.php

Schematic
[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but you have posted a cartoon wiring diagram which tells us nothing about the *schema* of your circuit. We use schematic diagrams with component symbols for that. Is there a schematic available?

Comment: @transistor I am sorry about that and unfortunately, there is not. This was the only diagram provided by the project creator

Comment: pkease examine the schematic diagrams at https://www.eleccircuit.com/lm324-quad-op-amp/ ..... those are good examples of how to correctly draw and label circuit diagrams of multiple components inside one IC package

Comment: I think you should talk to the original creator of the project. Also, you should try the MAX232 part without using the Arduino, and get that working first. Without a datasheet for the SP232 and MAX232 we don't know if they are compatible.

Comment: @Simba12 - This seems to be the same problem as described in your [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/548543/test-ultrasonic-sensors) where people asked for the schematic for the breadboard photo you gave there. Unless you have a *very* good reason (that I can't see) why this is separate from your previous question, then IMHO you should edit that question to include the schematic and any other new details, to keep everything in one place. Splitting a question into multiple pieces here is discouraged, as it prevents readers from seeing the whole context. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are obliged to measure all input signals that may affect T+ output on each pin and include is such a question.  Then read the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/146/SP232A-1888996.pdf) which ought to be linked for expected inputs.  Then make sense of your issues using Ohm's law for starters.  This is a bipolar charge pump with a level shifting inverter for input voltage.  Start with pin 16, 15, then 2,6 voltages

This is normal debug 101 and how you learn.
[image]